# Issues stripping special characters from text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

I have an Excel file that pulls in data from a csv, manipulates it a bit, and then saves it down as a series of text files.

There are some special characters in the source data that trip things up so I added this to strip them out

```
Const SpecialCharacters As String = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),{,[,],},?,â,€,™"

Function ReplaceSpecialCharacters(myString As String) As String

Dim newString As String
Dim char As Variant

newString = myString

For Each char In Split(SpecialCharacters, ",")
    newString = Replace(newString, char, "")
Next

ReplaceSpecialCharacters = newString

End Function
```

The issue is that this doesn't catch all of them. When I try to process the following text it slips through the above code and causes Excel to error out.

```
Heroâ€™s Village
```

I think the issue is that the special character isn't being recognized by Excel itself. I was only able to get the text to look like it does above by copying it out of Excel and pasting it into a different IDE. In Excel is displays as:

In the workbook
[image: Screenshot of workbook]

In the edit field
[image: Screenshot of edit field]

In the immediate window
[image: Screenshot of immediate window]

Based on [this site](https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) it looks like it's having issues displaying the `'` character, but how do I get it to fix/filter it out if it can't even read it properly in VBA itself?

Comment: There are many, many characters that are "special", especially if the strings contain *Unicode* characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
dim mystring as String
dim regex as new RegExp

Private Function rgclean(ByVal mystring As String) As String

'function that find and replace string if contains regex pattern
'returns str

    With regex

        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[^ \w]" 'regex pattern will ignore spaces, word and number characters...

    End With

    rgclean = regex.Replace(mystring, "") '.. and replaces everything else with ""

End Function
```

Try using regular expression.

Make sure you enable regular expression on:
Tools > References > checkbox: "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

Pass the "mystring" string variable into the function (rgclean). The function will check for anything that is not space, word[A-Za-z], or numbers[0-9], replace them with "", and returns the string.

The function will pretty much remove any symbols in the string. Any Numbers, Space, or Word will NOT be excluded.

Comment: Fine and straight forward solution :+)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the opposite approach.  Remove ALL characters that are not included in this group of 62:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQESTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

The code:

```
Const ValidCharacters As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQESTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

Function ReplaceSpecialCharacters(myString As String) As String
    
    Dim newString As String, L As Long, i As Long
    Dim char As Variant
    
    newString = myString
    L = Len(newString)
    
    For i = 1 To L
        char = Mid(newString, i, 1)
        If InStr(ValidCharacters, char) = 0 Then
            newString = Replace(newString, char, "@")
        End If
    Next i
    
    ReplaceSpecialCharacters = Replace(newString, "@", "")
    
End Function
```

[image]

**Note:**

You can also add characters to the string `ValidCharacters` if you want to retain them.

Comment: It's always fine to look for simple alternatives :+) - BTW instead of using a string constant with all valid characters you could shorten the condition as follows: `If Not char Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then` :-)